# iOS Swift Navigation unwind with redirection

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

I would like to implement the following: (I am using navigation controllers)
[image]

View A has several options which determine which path to take. The first displays view B which will then display View C using navigation controllers. The tool bar's first item performs a unwind to View A. Which works. The second item in the tool bar, I would like to unwind not only to A but redirect to View E.

The code in A view controller looks like this:

```
@IBAction func unwindToHomeController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toPerson", sender: self)
}
```

When I click on the second item in the tool bar, View E is displayed but view A is immediately displayed after a brief delay.

How do I stop the display of View A?

Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: First observation is you have 6 navigation controllers. You should only need one. Do you think each view controller needs to be embedded in its own navigation controller? Its not possible to diagnose what is currently going wrong without seeing more code, but its pointless at the moment until you get rid of those navigation controllers. Clean them out and then tackle what issues remain. Secondly, does it need to be a toolbar as opposed to a tab bar? Because using a tab bar controller will provide functionality  functionality for switching view controllers automatically.

Comment: I removed the extra navigation controllers... my bad I didn't understand you only needed the one. Not sure what code to show. I reference the unwind segue in A from the other views and the unwind code is shown. The code runs since View E is displayed briefly before A is displayed. I also can step through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait the animation finish to performSegue to E:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func unwindToA(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToE(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { 
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "E", sender: nil)
        }
        CATransaction.commit()
    }

}
```

[image: Normal unwind]

**UPDATED** To avoid the *flashing* showing A while pushing E

1) Remove the unwindToE function:

```
extension ViewController {

    @IBAction func unwindToA(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

//  @IBAction func unwindToE(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
//      CATransaction.begin()
//      CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { 
//          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "E", sender: nil)
//      }
//      CATransaction.commit()
//  }

}
```

2) Create a custom segue:

```
class MyUnwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        guard let nav = source.navigationController else { return }
        guard let root = nav.viewControllers.first else { return }
        let viewControllers = [root, destination]
        nav.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)

    }

}
```

3) Update the segue to MyUnwindSegue in storyboard (make sure the Module is selected to your project module rather than *empty*):

[image: Using custom unwind segue]

Comment: I had high hopes for this solution, however it did not work for me. I still see E briefly and then A is shown :(

Comment: Oops my bad, it works. Any suggestions on how I can keep A from flashing?

Comment: What do you mean **flashing**?

Comment: View A shows for a brief moment then view E appears. I prefer view not to show at all.